# how to install koha testing docker on windows？

Tags: perl

I want to install koha-testing-docker on window, but an error occurs during installation

error:
`koha-testing-docker-koha-1       | koha-testing-docker-koha-1       | Koha requires mpm_itk to be enabled within Apache in order to run. koha-testing-docker-koha-1       | Typically this can be enabled with: koha-testing-docker-koha-1       | koha-testing-docker-koha-1       |     sudo a2enmod mpm_itk`

Env：
system：window 11
docker-compose v2
vscode
koha-testing-docker latest

I want to fix this problem and start normally

Comment: *"but an error occurs during installation"* Which command did you use to install?

Comment: After using "docker-compose up", the container koha-1 reports an error

Comment: According to this https://git.koha-community.org/Koha-community/koha-testing-docker help page you should use `ktd up`

Comment: Can window use ktd? I can use ktd on ubuntu, but not on window. . .

Comment: *"Can Windows use ktd?"* Not sure, according to the help page https://git.koha-community.org/Koha-community/koha-testing-docker it should work on Windows.. If you are not following this setup, please update your question with the exact steps you did before running `docker-compose up`. Then we can try to reproduce.

Comment: Mine is running normally. I use git bash to run ktd up in the koha-docker directory, thank you.